# Question about local and global properties of functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, representation-theory, lie-groups

Call a lie group representation $G \subset GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ *rigid* if any infinitely differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ whose derivative is always in $G$, is of the form $f(x) = mx + b$, $m \in G$.

I am not sure if there is already a word for this.

Is there an easy way to tell if a representation is rigid? Maybe some necessary or sufficient conditions?

For example:

$GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is rigid  iff $n = 0$.

$O(n, \mathbb{R})$ is rigid because $f$ preserves the length of curves and angles between them, so it preserves the shortest path: lines.

$\mathbb{C}^* \subset GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is not rigid because there are holomorphic functions other than $mx + b$.

$SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is not rigid when $n > 1$ because there are many volume-preserving transformations, for example by Cavalieri's principle. It is rigid when $n \leq 1$.

$\mathbb{R}^* \subset GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ preserves lines and angles, so drawing a parallelogram shows it's rigid when $n \neq 1$.

Bear in mind that I don't know much about lie groups.